# Count Sketch variance

Tags: algorithm, streaming

I m studying a streaming algorithm for Count Sketch.

My professor introduce 3 algorithm ,

one is this

```
<Generate r in >
Update(i, c)
s = s + ri c
Estimate(i)
return ri s
```

the second is this

```
Initialization
<Generate r in {-1, 1}^n>
Update(i, c)
t = h(i)
s(t) = s(t) + ri c
Estimate(i)
t = h(i)
return ri s(t)
```

And the third is the compute n time same algorithm and take mean.
I understand that first just update the count, the second could be update the value with hash function.

But introduce concept for variance and expectation. Maybe for show that estimation is correct?

Professor suggest this resource, but i don't find easy for me

https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~farach/pubs/FrequentStream.pdf

i m following this one 
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse522/14sp/lectures/lect05.pdf

where in page 4 explain variance of my second algorithm.

Anyone can clarify me the link between variance and this agorithm?

Comment: What is a problem you are taking about?

Comment: i dont taken the link between variance and this algorithm @MBo